# How to track the uploaded size of a file in api laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8, laravel-api

I am developing a file system management using laravel 8.

I created a function that accept file.

```
public function uploadExperiment(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $uniqueId = time();
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filePath = $uniqueId . '/' . $fileName;

        Storage::disk('local')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));

        return response()->json(["success"=>true]);
    }
```

I need to track the uploaded size during the uploading process and this progress I need to save it in a database.

For example, If I want to upload a file with 2GB of size, It will takes time. So any idea about how to track it?

Answer (score 1):

maybe do you want create this:

```
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-laravel-file-upload-with-progress-bar-exampleexample.html
```

to get size file upload in laravel use:

```
$size = $request->file('file')->getSize();
```

maybe could use this for get % of your upload you can use jquery. but if you want to do in php, with this example i think that you have one idea that you could to do:

```
function timeout_trigger() {
   var loaded = file.getLoaded(); // loaded part
   p = parseInt(loaded / size);

   $(".progress").css("max-width",p+"%");
   $(".progress-view").text(p+"%");
   if(p!=100) {
       setTimeout('timeout_trigger()', 20);
   }
}
timeout_trigger();
```

i think that you have one form and you send it with `POST` for this use this function.

Comment: Please don't submit links alone. Links tend to stop working at some point; please elaborate you answer.

Comment: I am developing an api. So during the execution of this function, i need to track the uploaded size and transfer it to percentage and insert it in a database. The frontend app should call another function to check the progress from the database and then the front app will display it. I am not developing the frontend using laravel. There is a c++ desktop application will request this function. any idea about how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: @AliWehbi hhow do you said in your quetion that API it´s in laravel 8... for this i comented this link. i don´t know of C++ i know php, laravel, javascript, etc... i edited my response with one function that you can use to get size of your file. but i can´t help you to get % upload of your file, because i don´t know how ,could getting % upload in c++

Comment: i am not telling you that the function should be written in c++. what i said that the frontend app (which is desktop app developed using c++) need to talk with my backend app (which is developed using php laravel). So here the frontend needs to upload a file by calling my api and attach in it's body (POST REQUEST) the file. So I need to track the progress of the uploading file in my backend service (PHP, LARAVEL).